# Sending ZIP-archive with multipart/form-data POST in Android App

Tags: android, post, upload, multipart, form-data

I'm trying to post a ZIP-archive.

I have a website, where a file can be uploaded. The file is simply picked with a file chooser. When the "upload"-button is clicked, the website reloads itself. Before the site reloads, it checks, if there was a file submitted with POST. So if a file was chosen, the file is copied to a folder (including some renaming operations). This is the whole upload process on my website, and it works fine.

I want to use this service in my Android app. I just want to submit the file, so that the PHP code can do the rest. I followed some SO-posts and tutorials, but after a check with fileZilla, I sadly noticed, that there was no file in the directory, where it should be.

I am using an AsyncTask. I have three classes which extend AsyncTask, so I am familiar with that. The AsyncTask-Code seems to work fine, too. The problem is my upload code in the doInBackground-method.

Thats how my code looks like:

```
protected String doInBackground(String... sUrl)
{
    HttpURLConnection conn = null;
    DataOutputStream dOut = null;
    DataInputStream dIn = null;

    String filename = path;
    String lineEnd = "\r\n";
    String twoHyphens = "--";
    String boundary = "*****";

    int bytesRead, bytesAvailable, bufferSize;
    byte[] buffer;
    int maxBufferSize = 1*1024*1024;
    String urlString = Constants.URL_UPLOAD;

    try
    {
        // ********************** Client Request

        FileInputStream fileIn = new FileInputStream(new File(filename));


        URL url =  new URL(urlString);

        conn = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
        conn.setDoInput(true);
        conn.setDoOutput(true);
        conn.setUseCaches(false);
        conn.setRequestMethod("POST");
        conn.setRequestProperty("Connection", "Keep-Alive");
        conn.setRequestProperty("Content-Type", "multipart/form-data);boundary="+boundary);
        conn.setRequestProperty("Cookie", Constants.COOKIE_KEY + "=" + Constants.cookie);

        dOut = new DataOutputStream(conn.getOutputStream());
        dOut.writeBytes(twoHyphens + boundary + lineEnd);
        dOut.writeBytes("Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"fileupload\";filename=\"" + path + "\"" + lineEnd);
        dOut.writeBytes(lineEnd);

        bytesAvailable = fileIn.available();
        bufferSize = Math.min(bytesAvailable, maxBufferSize);
        buffer = new byte[bufferSize];
        bytesRead = fileIn.read(buffer, 0, bufferSize);

        while(bytesRead > 0)
        {
            dOut.write(buffer, 0, bufferSize);
            bytesAvailable = fileIn.available();
            bufferSize = Math.min(bytesAvailable, maxBufferSize);
            bytesRead = fileIn.read(buffer, 0, bufferSize);
        }

        dOut.writeBytes(lineEnd);
        dOut.writeBytes(twoHyphens + boundary + twoHyphens + lineEnd);

        fileIn.close();
        dOut.flush();
        dOut.close();
    }
    catch(MalformedURLException ex)
    {
        Log.e("Debug", "error: " + ex.getMessage(), ex);
    }
    catch(IOException ioex)
    {
        Log.e("Debug", "error: " + ioex.getMessage(), ioex);
    }

    try
    {
        dIn = new DataInputStream(conn.getInputStream());
        String str;

        while((str = dIn.readLine()) != null)
        {
            Log.e("Debug", "Server Response " + str);
            responseData = str;
        }

        dIn.close();
    }
    catch(IOException ioex)
    {
        Log.e("Debug", "error: " + ioex.getMessage(), ioex);
    }
    return null;
}
```

I think, my error is in that line:

```
dOut.writeBytes("Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"fileupload\";filename=\"" + path + "\"" + lineEnd);
```

I think that line defines the Http-Header. 
First, I just used the String for "name" which was used in other Posts. Some research showed me, that I have to use the value of the name-tag of that field of my form, which contains the value, which I want to post. In my case that would be the file chooser, which has the name "fileupload". (Or should I take the name of my form, which is "upload"?)
Another point, which confuses me is the value of "filename". Should I use the whole path, for example "path/to/android.app.zip" or should I just use the filename: "android.app.zip"?

Additionally I think, that there have to be more errors, because I tried all combinations of name and filename.

I hope someone finds the error(s).

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution, and it works.
I didn't change much, but I think there where some minor bugs, which haven't been mentioned in the other posts. I will comment some important points in my code. Additionally I added a 777 permission to the directory on my server. Don't know it that helped, but, as I said, after the given permissions and the bug fixes my code works.

```
protected String doInBackground(String... sUrl)
{
    HttpURLConnection conn = null;
    DataOutputStream dOut = null;
    String lineEnd = "\r\n";
    String twoHyphens = "--";
    String boundary = "*****";
    int bytesRead, bytesAvailable, bufferSize;
    byte[] buffer;
    int maxBuffersize = 1*1024*1024;
    File file = new File(path);  

     //path was declared in the constructor of my AsyncTask-Class. 
     // path has to look like this: /storage/some/dirs/myarchive.zip, when you use a .zip
    //At this point it is clear, that you have to use the full path, but many posts just used
    // a simple name like "file" as an example in the following code, which confused me.

    try
    {
        FileInputStream fileIn = new FileInputStream(file);
        URL url =  new URL(Constants.URL_UPLOAD);

        conn = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
        conn.setDoInput(true);
        conn.setDoOutput(true);
        conn.setUseCaches(false);
        conn.setRequestProperty("Cookie", Constants.COOKIE_KEY + "=" + Constants.cookie);

    //There wasn't even one tutorial or post, which uses cookies. That was a problem, too.
    //When you have a serious website, not just an example, then you possibly use cookies.
    //My constant "COOKIE_KEY" describes the cookie key (or name) you defined in your php code
    //and .cookie is just the value. For example it could look like this "user_cookie=MrFoo", when the cookie contains the username of a "MrFoo"

        conn.setRequestMethod("POST");
        conn.setRequestProperty("Connection", "Keep-Alive");
        conn.setRequestProperty("ENCTYPE", "multipart/form-data");
        conn.setRequestProperty("Content-Type", "multipart/form-data;boundary=" + boundary);
        conn.setRequestProperty("fileupload", path);

        dOut = new DataOutputStream(conn.getOutputStream());
        dOut.writeBytes(twoHyphens + boundary + lineEnd);
        dOut.writeBytes("Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"fileupload\";filename=\"" + path + "\"" + lineEnd);

    //Here you have to use the field in your html/php-code, which contains the file after "name"
    //In my case it was a file chooser (input type="file"), which has the name="fileupload". 
    //There wasn't any post again, where it was explained what kind of value is expected here.


        dOut.writeBytes(lineEnd);

        bytesAvailable = fileIn.available();
        bufferSize = Math.min(bytesAvailable, maxBuffersize);
        buffer = new byte[bufferSize];
        bytesRead = fileIn.read(buffer, 0, bufferSize);

        while(bytesRead > 0)
        {
            dOut.write(buffer, 0, bufferSize);
            bytesAvailable = fileIn.available();
            bufferSize = Math.min(bytesAvailable, maxBuffersize);
            bytesRead = fileIn.read(buffer, 0, bufferSize);
        }

        dOut.writeBytes(lineEnd);
        dOut.writeBytes(twoHyphens + boundary + twoHyphens + lineEnd);

        responseCode = conn.getResponseCode();
        String responseMessage = conn.getResponseMessage();

        Log.i("UPLOAD", "HTTP Response is: " + responseCode + ": " + responseMessage);

        if(responseCode == 200)
        {
            return null;
        }

        fileIn.close();
        dOut.flush();
        dOut.close();
    }
        catch(MalformedURLException e)
        {
            return e.toString();
        }
    catch(Exception e)
    {
        return e.toString();
    }

    return responseCode + "";
}
```

If anyone wants to see the other code, like the onPostExecute, see here:

```
private Context context;
    private ProgressDialog dialog;
    private String path;
    private PowerManager.WakeLock wakeLock;
    private int responseCod    

public UploadTask(Context ctx, ProgressDialog dialog, String path)
    {
        context = ctx;
        this.dialog = dialog;
        this.path = path;
        responseCode = 0;

    }



    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute()
    {
        super.onPreExecute();

        //locks CPU to prevend shut down during download

        PowerManager pm = (PowerManager) context.getSystemService(Context.POWER_SERVICE);
        wakeLock = pm.newWakeLock(PowerManager.PARTIAL_WAKE_LOCK, getClass().getName());
        wakeLock.acquire();
        dialog.show();
    }

    @Override
    protected void onProgressUpdate(Integer... progress)
    {
        super.onProgressUpdate(progress);

        dialog.setIndeterminate(false);
        dialog.setMax(100);
        dialog.setProgress(progress[0]);
    }

    protected void onPostExecute(String result)
    {
        wakeLock.release();
        dialog.dismiss();

        if(result != null)
            Toast.makeText(context, "Upload error: " + result, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        else
            Toast.makeText(context, "File uploaded!!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
```

There's just a progress dialog, and other stuff.

I hope I could help anyone.